# Bootstrap Collapse Accordion: Opening a panel by JavaScript does not close other open panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have an accordion which uses Bootstrap Collapse. When I click on any panel, it opens it and closes other open panels. But when I try to open a panel using JavaScript, other open panels does not close automatically.

```js
function openBreakfast() {
 $('#add-breakfast-form').collapse('show');
}

function openLunch() {
 $('#add-lunch-form').collapse('show');
}

function openDinner() {
 $('#add-dinner-form').collapse('show');
}

function openSnacks() {
 $('#add-snacks-form').collapse('show');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.m-t-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="food-tracker-accordion" role="tablist" class="panel-group m-t-20">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-breakfast-form">Add Breakfast</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-breakfast-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Breakfast form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-lunch-form">Add Lunch</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-lunch-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Lunch form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-dinner-form">Add Dinner</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-dinner-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Dinner form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-snacks-form">Add Snacks</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-snacks-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Snacks form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="m-t-20">
  <button onclick="openBreakfast()">Open Breakfast</button>
  <button onclick="openLunch()">Open Lunch</button>
  <button onclick="openDinner()">Open Dinner</button>
  <button onclick="openSnacks()">Open Snacks</button>
</div>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Another interesting thing is that if I click on any panel to close, opening that panel by JavaScript closes all other open panels.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is hide the panel which is opened before and you can do it by using `$('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');` like this

```js
function openBreakfast() {
  $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
 $('#add-breakfast-form').collapse('show');
}

function openLunch() {
 $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
 $('#add-lunch-form').collapse('show');
}

function openDinner() {
 $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
 $('#add-dinner-form').collapse('show');
}

function openSnacks() {
 $('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
 $('#add-snacks-form').collapse('show');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.m-t-20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="food-tracker-accordion" role="tablist" class="panel-group m-t-20">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-breakfast-form">Add Breakfast</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-breakfast-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Breakfast form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-lunch-form">Add Lunch</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-lunch-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Lunch form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-dinner-form">Add Dinner</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-dinner-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Dinner form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div role="tab" class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#food-tracker-accordion" href="#add-snacks-form">Add Snacks</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="add-snacks-form" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Add Snacks form
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="m-t-20">
  <button onclick="openBreakfast()">Open Breakfast</button>
  <button onclick="openLunch()">Open Lunch</button>
  <button onclick="openDinner()">Open Dinner</button>
  <button onclick="openSnacks()">Open Snacks</button>
</div>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it toggles the panels even if we are using `.collapse('show')`.

Comment: I had a similar workaround in my mind and I tried that and it works fine. My workaround is to use `$('#food-tracker-accordion .panel-collapse').not('#add-breakfast-form').collapse('hide');` instead of `$('.panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');`.